# Magento 2 : How to set the Title of Page in Admin Grid using UI_COMPONENT

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, grid, uicomponent

I have created a custom module using UI_COMPONENT. Everything worked properly, but unable to set the Page Title.

[image]

Index layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <uiComponent name="testing_item_grid"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Adding Solution: In Adminhtml Controller prepend your title text.

Here is the code:

```
namespace Testing\test\Controller\Adminhtml\Index;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;
use Magento\Backend\App\Action;
class Index extends Action{
    public function execute() {

        $resultPage = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_PAGE);
        $resultPage->getConfig()->getTitle()->prepend(__(" Custom Grid"));
        return $resultPage;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

just go to your **module's adminhtml index layout** and set your title inside **`head tag`**:

```
<head>
    <title>
        Your title goes here...
    </title>
</head>
```

or try **`prepend(__("Title"));`**

```
public function execute()
{
    $resultPage = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_PAGE);
    $resultPage->getConfig()->getTitle()->prepend(__(" Custom Grid"));
    return $resultPage;
}
```

Comment: already head is there, but it not showing

Comment: @Rahul Singh added another solution

Comment: changed $this->resultPageFactory->create() to $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_PAGE), after that it worked. Thanks

Comment: yeah! that's great!

Comment: try to add below code inside layout file

<referenceBlock name="page.title">
                <action method="setPageTitle">
                    <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">Your Page Title</argument>
                </action>
            </referenceBlock>

Comment: It worked thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

[image]

You can update code into your grid controller & change title whatever you want.

```
use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;

 protected $resultPageFactory;

    public function __construct(
            Context $context,
            PageFactory $resultPageFactory,

        ) {
            parent::__construct($context);
            $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;

        }
            public function execute()
                {
                    /** @var \MAgento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Page $resultPage */
                    $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();
                    $resultPage->getConfig()->getTitle()->prepend(__('Dealer Settlement Report
        '));
                    return $resultPage;
                }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this within body tag of your layout file

> view/adminhtml/layout/id_foldername_classname.xml

```
<body>
        <referenceBlock name="page.title">
            <action method="setPageTitle">
                <argument name="title" xsi:type="string">Greetings</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
</body>
```